# C# parse list data into excel

Tags: c#, html-table, excel-interop

I am currently selecting HTML Table data from a webpage, and storing any content that contains an Anchor tag, and then exporting that list to display in Excel.

The issue I am having is that I am unable to get it to display properly in Excel.
The List does contain the correct data, but on excel its only displaying the last item in the list (seems like it is overwriting each time it iterates through the list).

The List (cellList) is the list that contains the correct data, have tried many different variations to try to get it to display correctly but just cant seem to pinpoint why the below isn't working correctly.

I have used more or less the same foreach code to display a List from SQL Data into excel the same way.

Any help, or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
HtmlTable tabletest = ActiveBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlTable>("MainContent_ucLicensees_gviGeneric");
IList<HtmlAnchor> myList = tabletest.Find.AllByTagName<HtmlAnchor>("a");

foreach (HtmlAnchor item in myList)
{
    string celltext = item.InnerText.ToString();
    List<string> cellList = new List<string>();
    cellList.Add(celltext);

    int row = 2;
    int col = 2;
    foreach (var cellitem in cellList)
    {
        excelApp.Cells[row, col] = cellitem;
        row++;
        if (cellList.IndexOf(cellitem) == cellList.Count - 1)
        {
            col = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this list produce data with multiple columns? There is only a single list, shouldn't that produce a single column? I don't see the need for the `cellList` list and the second loop. It seems that you should only loop once and simply increment the row number every time.

Comment: Correct, it is just 1 column for the above code (there are other columns being created by another list but that one displays correctly).  When I try to just display the "myList" list, I cant get it to display the actual items inside, it will show just HtmlAnchor references like (HtmlAnchor:<a href="mailto:">), it is only when I display the 2nd list (cellList) that I can see the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you should only loop once and simply increment the row number every time. Something like this should work:

```
int row = 2; //Should this be 1?
int col = 2; //Should this be 1?

foreach (HtmlAnchor item in myList)
{
    string celltext = item.InnerText.ToString();

    excelApp.Cells[row, col] = celltext;

    row++;   
}
```

Comment: The above unfortunately, has the same issue, it is only showing the last item in the list in the 1st row (row 2). It is like it is now going to the next row when it should.  also for the questions on the int variables Row 1 holds the headers and Column 1 holds other data is why row/col = 2

Comment: You are sure that you are incrementing `row` every iteration?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `myList` contains more than 1 item?

Comment: int row = 2; int col = 2;  was the issue! because I hadn't moved them out of the foreach loop code, soon as I moved them out, like you have done above, it worked perfectly. Thank you for helping Yacoub, I am not sure why having them in the foreach loop causes it to not work, but lesson learned!!

Comment: You are welcome. If you keep them inside the loop, then the value will be reset to 2 each iteration which will cause the value to be always written to row 2.